# AngularJS. Route to parent if it has been already routed

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have this route configuration:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/clients', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html'
    })
    .when('/clients/:client_id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($route, $routeParams) {
                $route.current.params.client_id = parseInt($route.current.params.client_id, 10);
                return;
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/objections', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.objections.html'
    })
    .when('/objections/:objection_id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.objections.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($route, $routeParams) {
                $route.current.params.objection_id = parseInt($route.current.params.objection_id, 10);
                return;
            }
         }
     });
```

How to make that way:
1) I started from page #/clients;
2) Go to #/clients/2;
3) Go to #/questions
4) when i clicked to link #/clients i have to be redirected to the last viewed clients ( #/clients/2 ), not #/clients .

How to do it?

Comment: what if you want to list all clients?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing what you want: you can use a shared service (factory in our case) to store the latest visited `client_id`.
This way, when you enter the `/clients` route, you check that service for the `client_id`, and redirect to that client's page:

```
angular.module('your-app-name')

    // define the routing system
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/clients', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html',
                controller: 'ClientCtrl'
            })
            .when('/clients/:client_id', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html',
                resolve: {
                    myApp: function($route, $routeParams, sharedData) {
                        sharedData.client_id = $route.current.params.client_id = parseInt($route.current.params.client_id, 10);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
            // other routes go here
    })

    // define the client controller
    .controller('ClientCtrl', function($location, sharedData) {
        if(sharedData.client_id) {
            $location.path('clients/' + sharedData.client_id);
        }
        // other controller logic
    })

    // define the sharedData factory
    .factory('sharedData', function() {
        // it's an empty container for now
        var sharedData = {};
        return sharedData;
    });
```

Although it's not the cleanest solution, I think it will suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do some operations in routing before controller so i use this way:

```
myApp.value('last_visits', {
    client: null,
    objection: null,
    question: null,
    finalQuestion: null
})
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/clients', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($location, last_visits) {
                if ( last_visits.client!==null ) {
                    $location.path('/clients/'+last_visits.client);
                }
            }
        }
    }).when('/clients/:client_id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.clients.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($route, $routeParams, last_visits) {
                $route.current.params.client_id = parseInt($route.current.params.client_id, 10);
                last_visits.client = $route.current.params.client_id;
                return;
            }
        }
    }).when('/objections', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.objections.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($location, last_visits) {
                if ( last_visits.objection!==null ) {
                    $location.path('/objections/'+last_visits.objection);
                }
            }
        }
    }).when('/objections/:objection_id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin.objections.html',
        resolve: {
            myApp: function($route, $routeParams, last_visits) {
                $route.current.params.objection_id = parseInt($route.current.params.objection_id, 10);
                last_visits.objection = $route.current.params.objection_id;
                return;
            }
        }
```